# How to find N largest strings in a managed core dump using WinDbg?

Tags: .net, windbg

I have a dump that has 26GB of strings - over 3.5 million strings. The large object heap has only 18 of them taking slightly more than 2.5MB - checked with `!sosex.dumpgen` command.

Gen 2 has most of them. How can I get N largest, except by getting all of them into a log file and then analysing it outside of WinDbg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was possible with [Netext](https://netext.codeplex.com/), but it's only close to SOSEx' `!strings`, so it needs some more scripting

```
0:000> .load F:\...\netext\2.0.1.5580\x86\NetExt.dll
NetExt version 2.0.1.5580 Aug  3 2015
License and usage can be seen here: !whelp license
Check Latest version: !wupdate
For help, type !whelp (or in WinDBG run: '.browse !whelp')
Questions and Feedback: http://netext.codeplex.com/discussions 
Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Rodney Viana (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana) 
Type: !windex -tree or ~*e!wstack to get started

0:000> !windex
Starting indexing at 20:55:54
Indexing finished at 20:55:54
30,707 Bytes in 343 Objects
Index took 00:00:00

0:000> !wfrom /nofield /type System.String where (m_stringLength>50) select m_stringLength
0n100
0n137
0n130
0n100
...
```

To get rid of the `0n`prefix, we use `$substr(m_stringLength,2,100)`.

Like this we get an overview of the lengths of strings. This list needs some sorting, so let's use a `.shell` and the DOS `sort /R` command:

```
!! -ci "!wfrom /nospace /nofield /type System.String where (m_stringLength>50) select $substr(m_stringLength,2,100)" sort /R
```

From the result, let's get the top N items using a loop and skipping some items. Replace `0n2` by the number of items you want minus 1.

```
.foreach /pS 0n2 /ps 999999 (length {!! -ci "!wfrom /nospace /nofield /type System.String where (m_stringLength>50) select $substr(m_stringLength,2,100)" sort /R}) {.echo length}
```

Now that we know the minimum length of the top N strings, we can apply it to the original `!wfrom` command again.

Hey, wasn't that easy? Output to a text file sometimes is a quite good solution...

Comment: Oh boy, I did end up outputting to a text file the entire content of `!dumpheap -mt 00007fff6c9c16b8`, where `00007fff6c9c16b8` is the MT of string.

Answer (score 1):

> sosex has **!strings** command which has a switch where we can specify
>   min length.

Sorry I am not near a machine where i can try sosex. but it should be like e.g. !strings -m 1000 . You can try the soshelp command and get this *!sosex.help strings* This will print all strings which are only more than 1000.Like this i used to try and give large values like 10000 and get large strings.